# How to downgrade version of Webpack?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I've installed Webpack through NPM in my ASP.NET core Web project. And now version of webpack is:  `2.4.1`. However, I need to install the following version of webpack: `2.1.0-beta.25`.

I've tried to use the following command:

```
npm install webpack@2.1.0-beta.25
```

But it seems that this command is not installed a desired version of Webpack cause this command `npm view webpack version` shows: `2.4.1`

How can I downgrade to `2.1.0-beta.25`?

Comment: I didnt found webpack@2.1.0-beta.25 but there is webpack@2.1.0-beta.28 maybe try this one...  to check all versions of webpack run "npm view webpack versions" ;)

Comment: `npm view webpack version` probably shows the latest available version, not the version you have installed.

Comment: You should probably make sure your global and repository versions match, also

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`npm view`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/view) does not show the installed packages, but information from the package repository. If you omit the version, it will always show the latest version.

You can use [`npm ls`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/ls) instead:

```
npm ls webpack
```

Comment: I've tries this command and see many errors: `+--ERR! peer dep missing
UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY`, but can't see the version of webpack. Do you know what the problem is?

Comment: @StepUp You have to be more specific. What peer dependencies are missing?

Comment: The following dependencies: 
`+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/common@2.2.1
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/core@2.2.1
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/platform-browser@2.2.1
`
but I cannot know through `npm ls webpack` the installed version till I resolve dependencies?

Answer (score 13):

Try

```
npm uninstall webpack

npm install webpack@2.1.0-beta.25
```

or

```
npm uninstall webpack --save

npm install webpack@2.1.0-beta.25 --save
```

Comment: how can I see installed version of webpack?

Comment: `npm list | grep webpack` or you can also try `npm info webpack version`

Answer (score 3):

Just change the version in your `**package.json**` and hit `npm i` and it should have installed the mentioned version in package.json. for confirmation go to **webpack** folder in node_modules and read **package.json** and you should be able to see the same version. Or just do `npm show webpack version` and it will show you the installed version